# Trace map argument for number fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $K \subset L$ a finite (and therefore inevitably algebraic)
extension of number fields. Let $O_K$ and $O_L$ be the ring of integers
of $K$ and $L$. The goal is to show that that $O_L$ is finite
$O_K$-module. The later means that there exist
$l_1, l_2,..., l_m \in O_L $ such that $O_L = l_1 \cdot O_K 
+ l_2 \cdot O_K + ... + l_m \cdot O_K$.

Now in my lecture notes is noted that this result follows from
an 'easy application of the so called trace map argument'.

I have to confess that I nowhere heard about such
'trace map argument' in that context and I would very thankful
if somebody has an idea what it is and elaborate how this
argument is used here.

My ideas: There exist a $K$-bilinear 'trace map' $Tr: L \times L \to K, (x,y) 
\mapsto tr(x \cdot y)$ where $x \cdot y$ is regarded as $K$-linear
endomorphism $L \to L$. Since we are dealing with number fields
it is known that $Tr$ is not degenerated (the extension is separated).
The field extension $K \subset L$ is assumed to be finite, so there exist
a $K$-basis $x_1, ..., x_m \in L$ with $L \cong K^m \cong
x_1K \oplus x_2K \oplus ... \oplus x_mK$.

Now seemingly the trick is to find other basis
$y_1, y_2, ..., y_m \in O_L$ (probably by 'clearing denominators
of the $x_i$) and to show that these $y_i$ are still linear independent $(1)$
over $K$ and for every $l \in L$ holds:

$l \in O_L $ iff $l = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i y_i $ with $a_i \in O_K$ $(2)$

I conjecture that $(2)$ can be derived by the mentioned 'trace map
argument' while $(1)$ can be proved independently. But it is also not
clear how. The $x_i$ form a $K$-basis and not a $L$-basis, therefore
multiplying the basis elements by $x_i$ by elements from $L^*$
could destroy their linear independence, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the basis $y_1,\dots,y_m$ we need to show that $K\mathcal{O}_L=L$, so we can multiply the $x_i$ with some non-zero elements $r_i\in K$ to get elements $y_i=r_ix_i$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$ which will then of course still form a $K$-basis of $L$. To see $K\mathcal{O}_L=L$, let $x\in L$. As $x$ is algebraic over $K$ there are some $a_i$ with $$x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_n=0$$
Let $d\in \mathcal{O}_K$ be a common denominator of the $a_i$. By multiplying the above equation with $d^nx$ we see that $dx$ satisfies a monic polynomial equation over $\mathcal{O}_K$, hence $dx\in \mathcal{O}_L$ and it follows that $x\in K\mathcal{O}_L$.
It follows as argued at the beginning that we may choose a basis $y_1,\dots,y_m$ of $L/K$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$. Let $B$ be the $\mathcal{O}_K$-submodule of $\mathcal{O}_L$ spanned by the $y_i$. Define $B^\#$ to be the *dual module* of $B$, i.e. $$B^\#=\{x\in L\mid Tr_{L/K}(xy)\in\mathcal{O}_K \text{ for all } y\in B\}$$ By definition of $B^\#$ we have a well defined map $B^\#\to \mathcal{O}_K^n$ given by $x\mapsto (Tr_{L/K}(xy_1),\dots,Tr_{L/K}(xy_m))$. Since $L/K$ is separable the trace form is non-degenerate, hence $B^\#\to\mathcal{O}_K^n$ is injective. As $\mathcal{O}_K$ is noetherian it follows that $B^\#$ is a finite $\mathcal{O}_K$-module. Since $\mathcal{O}_L\subset B^\#$ using again that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is noetherian we see that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is finite over $\mathcal{O}_K$.
(Actually the fact that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is noetherian is usually proved by the same argument, but over $\Bbb Z$)

Comment: Why the fact that $O_K$ is noetherian and $\mathcal{O}_L\subset B^\#$
imply that $B$ is finite over $O_K$?

Comment: additionally, in your proof do you maybe mean 'As $\mathcal{O}_K$ is noetherian it follows that $B^\#$ is a finite $\mathcal{O}_K$-module'? Indeed, $B$ is finite by contruction, so it makes more sense to conclude that $B^{\#}$ is a finite. In fact, seemingly the noetherianess we need to apply something like this: $A$ noeth ring, $N \subset M$ are $A$-modules and $M$ finite. Then $N$ also finite?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to say that $B^\#$ is finite over $\mathcal{O}_K$

Comment: Yes, exactly, we need the noetherianess to conclude that submodules of f.g. modules are again f.g.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this sounds reasonable. Starting with a basis $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ of an extension $L / K$, you can multiply them with elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$ to assume that they in fact lie in $\mathcal{O}_L$. After that, one has the following result, whose proof I'll more or less quote.

**Lemma (cf. Neukirch, I.2.9).** Write $d$ for the discriminant of $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$. Then $d\mathcal{O}_L \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_1 + \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_n$.

*Proof:* If $\alpha = c_1 \alpha_1 + \cdots + c_n \alpha_n \in \mathcal{O}_L$, with coefficients $c_i$ in $K$, then the $c_i$ are a solution of the system of linear equations
$$\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i\alpha) = \sum_j \operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i\alpha_j)c_j,$$
and as $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i \alpha) \in \mathcal{O}_K$, they are given as the quotient of an element of $\mathcal{O}_K$ by the determinant $\det \operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i \alpha_j) = d$. Therefore the $dc_j$ live in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and the desired result follows.

I presume this is enough to infer finite generation of $\mathcal{O}_L$ over $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: not quite, what we know not is that each $a \in O_L$ can be writen
as $a=\frac{ad}{d}=  \sum \frac{c_i}{d} \alpha_i$. Trivially also holds
$\mathcal{O}_K \alpha_1 + \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_n \subset 
\mathcal{O}_L$. but I not know how I can get rid of this 
denominator. Sorry, if it's too trivial but I can't find a way 
to finish it.

Comment: I thought last time again about your last remark that
from $d\mathcal{O}_L \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_1 
+ \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_n$ is enough to conclude that
$O_L$ is finite over $O_K$ and I still curiuos which
argument you have here in mind. The argument which I found is that we can use the fact that
if $A$ is a noethr ring and $N \subset M$ are $A$-modules 
where $M$ is finite $A$-module, then $N$ is also finite $A$-mod.

Comment: In our case we take $N:= O_L$ and 
$M:= \mathcal{O}_K \frac{\alpha_1}{d} 
+ \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \frac{\alpha_n}{d}$ and
because the Lemma implies 
$O_L \subset \mathcal{O}_K \frac{\alpha_1}{d} 
+ \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \frac{\alpha_n}{d}$ we can apply the 
fact I mentioned. For sake of curiosity was this exactly the argument you had there 
in your last remark in 
mind in order to finish the proof of the statement in the 
question using your Lemma or inteded you there to use
another idea?