# For number fields $L/K$ the ring of integers $O_L$ is finite over $O_K$ as an immediate consequence of a Lemma from Neukirch

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K \subset L$ a finite extension of number fields. Let $O_K$ and $O_L$ be
the rings of integers of $K$ and $L$. The goal of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007472/trace-map-argument-for-number-fields) was
to elaborate that $O_L$ is finite $O_K$-module. Although the question is
answered, Jeroen remarked that this claim could alternatively proved using
following Lemma from Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory:

Let be a basis of finite extension $L/K$. Multiplying them by suitable
elements from $O_K$ ('clearing the denominators') we can assume that all
$\alpha_i$ lie in $O_L$. Then

**Lemma (cf. Neukirch, I$.2.9$).** Let $d \in K$ be the discriminant of
$\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$. Then
$d\mathcal{O}_L \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_1 + \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_n$.

Then we have a chain of inclusions
$$d\mathcal{O}_L \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_1 + \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_n
\subseteq \mathcal{O}_L.$$

But I not know how from this we can conclude
$O_L = \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_1 + \cdots + \mathcal{O}_K \alpha_n$. Equivalently
how can I show that for any $a \in O_L$ which by the **Lemma** can be written as
$a=\frac{ad}{d}=  \sum \frac{c_i}{d} \alpha_i$ we can conclude that
$c_i/d \in O_K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in this case

$$\mathcal O_L\subseteq d^{-1}\alpha_1\mathcal O_K+\cdots+d^{-1}\alpha_n\mathcal O_K$$

and the latter is a free $\mathcal O_K$-module and in particular finitely generated. We may consider the special case $K=\Bbb Q$ and $\mathcal O_K=\Bbb Z$. Then, $\mathcal O_L$ is as a submodule of a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring is itself finitely generated. This by passes the usual trace argument in so far as this argument is hidden in the lemma. Using this on $\mathcal O_K\subseteq\mathcal O_L$ for a finite extension of number fields $L/K$ then gives your result.

However, I am not completely sure if the $\alpha_i$ do form an integral basis necessarily. The argument I presented only proves that $\mathcal O_L$ is itself finitely generated and hence finite over $\mathcal O_K$ containing the latter (which is the question asked in the title and what the linked answer is concerned with; please correct me if your questions was something else).

Comment: clearly since we deal with number fields the $O_K$ has $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure, and therefore $A:=d^{-1}\alpha_1\mathcal O_K+\cdots+d^{-1}\alpha_n\mathcal O_K$ as well. But why is $A$ also a *free*  $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: by the way what you precisely mean by 'usual trace argument'?

Comment: @IsaktheXI The trace argument in the post you linked is to the best of my knowledge the standard approach for showing that the ring of integers of a number field is finitely generated.

Comment: @IsaktheXI I meant to write free $\mathcal O_K$-module. Using this asserstion then once for the trivial case $K=\Bbb Q$ generalizes it to arbitrary number fields, if I'm not mistaken. But I might've messed something up here. But this part is not really relevant for the question so I'll just remove it for now.

Comment: about this 'usual trace trick':In the linked post leoli1 as well Jeroen van der Meer used 
trace in their proofs. So as far as I understood you correctly when one 
talks about 'usual trace argument' in this context, conventially
one means the argument used by leoli1, right? That is this diagonal 
embedding of a $O_K$-module in $O_K^n$ for $n$ big enough via 
 $(Tr_{L/K}(\cdot y_1),...Tr_{L/K}(\cdot y_n)$, right?

Comment: @IsaktheXI Exactly.

Comment: About the question if the $\alpha_i$ build an integral basis of
$O_L$ over $O_K$: I don't know but I doubt, since in general you
cannot expect that for any $a=\frac{ad}{d}=  \sum \frac{c_i}{d} \alpha_i$
the discriminant $d$ divides all coefficients. Moreover $d$ is in general
not invertible in $O_K$.

Comment: I searched for a proof of the quoted fact 
$A$ noetherian ring 
$N \subset M$ are $A$ modules and $M$ finite, then $N$ is also finite 
and found only proofs which all work like this one:
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IJ

The problem is that it is not constructive, so they all not contain an 
explicit method
to construct a set generators of $N$ from generators of $M$.
Do you maybe know a constructive proof (if such one at all exists)?

Comment: @IsaktheXI I'm only aware of a non-constructive proof. If you're, however, interested in explicitely finding an integral basis for the ring of integers I'd recommend taking a look at Milne's *Algebraic Number Theory*.